# How to build a numpy matrix (from scratch, not existing before) adding calculated columns in a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

It is a task in school (parallel normalization of each column of a matrix) and besides other problems you may see, I found it particularly difficult to find something easy as the list = [] that you can list.append() entire lists in a loop to, without predefining dimensions.
Here is what I have so far with the line in question at the end. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

def fct_norm(col):
    mn = col.min()
    mx = col.max()
    col_norm = np.zeros((6, 1))
    for i in range(6):
        col_norm[i, 0] = (col[i] - mn) / (mx - mn)
    return col_norm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool()
    arr = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(6, 3))
```

```
maybe predefine arr_norm here?
```

```
    for i in range(2):
        print("i = ", i)
        col = arr[:, i]
        result = pool.map(fct_norm, [col])
        norm_arr = HOW_TO_ADD_EACH_RESULT_COLUMN_TO_A_NEW_ARRAY?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need to concatenate a number of columns is `np.hstack`. However, a big problem is  `pool.map`is not used in the correct way in the original code.

As written, there is no parallel execution of the columns, since each call to `pool.map` gets only a single column. The idea is to pass an iterator with several values at the same time - in this case, multiple columns to `pool.map`.

Since `numpy` loops over rows, rather than columns, the matrix must be transposed (using the `(...).T` operator. Also, after the `pool` is finished, it is good measure to close it. One way to handle this automatically, is to use a context (i.e., the `with Pool() as pool:` construct, as then it will close automatically.

This all taken together gives the following solution:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np


def fct_norm(col):
    mn = col.min()
    mx = col.max()
    col_norm = np.zeros((6, 1))
    for i in range(6):
        col_norm[i, 0] = (col[i] - mn) / (mx - mn)
    return col_norm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(6, 3))

    with Pool() as pool:
        norm_arr = np.hstack(pool.map(fct_norm, arr.T))

    # Here norm_arr is available for further operations.
```

Thus, the whole operation can be performed in two lines.

Comment: Thank you so much for your excellent help!! I have much to learn :)